# Text alignment within a geometry

Tags: three.js, aframe

I am trying to display text within a mesh that gets created using a component. Here is the component that creates a rectangular shape with rounded edges. I got it from  [github link for aframe-rounded](https://github.com/etiennepinchon/aframe-rounded)

Here is the code for this component

```
 AFRAME.registerComponent('rounded', {
  schema: {
    enabled: {default: true},
    width: {type: 'number', default: 1},
    height: {type: 'number', default: 1},
    radius: {type: 'number', default: 0.3},
    topLeftRadius: {type: 'number', default: -1},
    topRightRadius: {type: 'number', default: -1},
    bottomLeftRadius: {type: 'number', default: -1},
    bottomRightRadius: {type: 'number', default: -1},
    color: {type: 'color', default: "#F0F0F0"},
    opacity: {type: 'number', default: 1}    
  },
  init: function () {
    this.rounded = new THREE.Mesh( this.draw(), new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color: new THREE.Color(this.data.color), side: THREE.DoubleSide } ) );
    this.updateOpacity();
    this.el.setObject3D('mesh', this.rounded)
  },
  update: function () {
    if (this.data.enabled) {
      if (this.rounded) {
        this.rounded.visible = true;
        this.rounded.geometry = this.draw();
        this.rounded.material.color = new THREE.Color(this.data.color);
        this.updateOpacity();
      }
    } else {
      this.rounded.visible = false;
    }
  },
  updateOpacity: function() {
    if (this.data.opacity < 0) { this.data.opacity = 0; }
    if (this.data.opacity > 1) { this.data.opacity = 1; }
    if (this.data.opacity < 1) {
      this.rounded.material.transparent = true;
    } else {
      this.rounded.material.transparent = false;
    }
    this.rounded.material.opacity = this.data.opacity;
  },
  tick: function () {},
  remove: function () {
    if (!this.rounded) { return; }
    this.el.object3D.remove( this.rounded );
    this.rounded = null;
  },
  draw: function() {
    var roundedRectShape = new THREE.Shape();
    function roundedRect( ctx, x, y, width, height, topLeftRadius, topRightRadius, bottomLeftRadius, bottomRightRadius ) {
      if (!topLeftRadius) { topLeftRadius = 0.00001; }
      if (!topRightRadius) { topRightRadius = 0.00001; }
      if (!bottomLeftRadius) { bottomLeftRadius = 0.00001; }
      if (!bottomRightRadius) { bottomRightRadius = 0.00001; }
      ctx.moveTo( x, y + topLeftRadius );
      ctx.lineTo( x, y + height - topLeftRadius );
      ctx.quadraticCurveTo( x, y + height, x + topLeftRadius, y + height );
      ctx.lineTo( x + width - topRightRadius, y + height );
      ctx.quadraticCurveTo( x + width, y + height, x + width, y + height - topRightRadius );
      ctx.lineTo( x + width, y + bottomRightRadius );
      ctx.quadraticCurveTo( x + width, y, x + width - bottomRightRadius, y );
      ctx.lineTo( x + bottomLeftRadius, y );
      ctx.quadraticCurveTo( x, y, x, y + bottomLeftRadius );
    }

    var corners = [this.data.radius, this.data.radius, this.data.radius, this.data.radius];
    if (this.data.topLeftRadius != -1) { corners[0] = this.data.topLeftRadius; }
    if (this.data.topRightRadius != -1) { corners[1] = this.data.topRightRadius; }
    if (this.data.bottomLeftRadius != -1) { corners[2] = this.data.bottomLeftRadius; }
    if (this.data.bottomRightRadius != -1) { corners[3] = this.data.bottomRightRadius; }

    roundedRect( roundedRectShape, 0, 0, this.data.width, this.data.height, corners[0], corners[1], corners[2], corners[3] );
    return new THREE.ShapeBufferGeometry( roundedRectShape );
  },
  pause: function () {},
  play: function () {}
});
```

In order to display the text, here is how I am using it in my code

```
<a-entity rounded="width: 3; height: 1; color: #ff00ed; opacity: 0.4" text="align: left; baseline: bottom; anchor: left; wrapCount: 35; value: Animating color; width: 2.5" position="2 1 -3">
```

However, the text always shows up at the bottom or outside the mesh geometry. I have played around with values for baseline, anchor, wrapCount etc..but it never shows the text at the top of the mesh.

Here is the fiddle that shows the problem [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nirajupadhyay/g5bv8r7x/25/)

Could someone please help?

Comment: added fiddle to showcase the issue

Answer (score 0):

Changing the value of x and y to set the position of the rounded mesh solved this issue. Specifically this piece of code

```
roundedRect( roundedRectShape, 0, -1, this.data.width, this.data.height, corners[0], corners[1], corners[2], corners[3] );
```